# Multilevel (nested) model with paired data

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am new to multilevel models and I have the following experimental design:
[image]

I have 3 treatments. For each treatment, a group of families that have twins are taken. Some measure, for example height, is taken for each twin in 3 different time steps.
I want to analyze if the treatment has any effect on the height evolution of each couple of twins.

What kind of analysis would be appropiate? How can I take into account the correlation that could exist between each couple of twins? The nesting within family would solve that?
Sorry, but I'm new to this. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Has this experiment already taken place? You could use twins as matched controls and thus have each pair of twins have two different treatments. This is quite common in clinical science. As for the question... the title already answers it. Use a mixed/nested/multilevel model with a random effect for family and a nested effect for each individual due to the repeated measures.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question, if I were to distinguish between, let's say, the twin that was born first and the second and I wanted to analyze the evolution of the first-born twins, and the secondly-born twins under each treatment, would it be okay to consider it in two separate mixed models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, a mixed effects model, with random intercepts for individuals nested within families, is a good way to go. As for the question about first and second born, you could introduce a new variable, `parity`, which identifies this, as an individual-level variable.